# Difference between DEM raster in QGIS 2.18 and 3.4.4

Tags: dem, geotiff-tiff, qgis-3, qgis-2

I came across a really strange problem.

Untill today i always worked in QGIS 2.18. Now i wanted to upgraded to 3.4.4 ( it was already downloaded but hadn't used it yet)

When opening my QGIS project everything looked fine except the styling of the DEM raster was wrong. I thought it was a small issue because the project was build in an older version and i just decided to reload the raster layer and restyle it.

After reloading the DEM i noticed that the elevation was wrong.

This is the raster in QGIS 2.18 :

[image]

And now in QGIS 3.4.4 :

[image]

And i really don't know what the problem can be.. I tried googling it but as far as i know i'm the only one with this problem.

The DEM is originally a .pts file converted to a DEM raster with autocad C3D.

Does anybody have a clue what might be the problem?

Edit:

QGIS 2.18 min / max value:

[image]

QGIS 3.4.4min/max value:

[image]

UPDATE:

Still no solution for my problem. Today i made a new DEM raster using Autocad Civil 3D. Min = MAX?

[image]

This are my raster settings 
[image]

This is how it looks in the canvas :

[image]

This is the same DEM is autocad map :

[image]

Comment: @ahmadhanb I've added screen shots of the min/max values. They look the same for me?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the issue, but try to change the `Cumulative pixel count cut limits` in QGIS 3 to `2 - 98` (now it is 100). Anyway do not worry, if your question is different the community will skip the duplicate.

Comment: It was first 2 - 98. When you told me to look there i tried to change it to 100 before i took the screenshot in the hope it maybe worked. So that won't be the problem. But anyway thanks for the help

Comment: One more thing, when you change the min/max value, under min/max tab in symbology select the `Whole raster` and `Actual (slower)`

Comment: Return the global setting for cumulative count cut limits from 2 to 98 and don't touch the global settings until you understand what they do. Share the Layer -> Properties -> Symbology tab with its sections expanded form both (2.18 and 3.4) layers instead.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca i think i found the problem in one of your comment in an other post : "Offset is a fixed value added to all the cell values, it should be 0. Scale is a multiplying factor for all cell values, it should be 1. gdal_translate -a_offset 0 -a_scale 1 Surface1.tif somefilename.tif don't solve the issue" The problem is, i have never worked with Gdal. How does this work, rather new to the GIS work :)

Comment: Yes, the Autodesk issue. The GDAL command need to be written in the console (a Windows shell with some enviroment paths setted). For OSGeo4W users just run the OSGeo4W Shell app, navigate to the folder of the raster file and write the command there. For stand-alone versions of QGIS I don't remember, you need to search for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help. the strange thing is that before using Qgis3.4 i didn't had this problem.

Comment: I would believe that in previous versions of QGIS (or the version of GDAL that was installed with QGIS) the values of Offset and Scale metadata in the rasters were ignored.